# Generate a column of type 'double' in migration - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to create a column of type `double` in my database, I understand that in ruby there is no `double` type and that to simulate this type of value I have to use `:scale` and `:precision`

How can i solve this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am working with mysql

Comment: Doesn't `t.decimal :column_name, precision: 4, scale: 3` work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the precision and scale in your migration.

```
class AddCostToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :bookings, :cost, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 2
  end
end
```

> **Precision** defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing
>   the total number of digits in the number.
>
> **Scale** defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the number of digits after the decimal point.